# An error in the system of rating heroes in One Punch Man

Tags: one-punch-man

I think that the rating system of heroes in One Punch Man has an error, what I understood from the anime is that if someone reaches Top 1 in some X-class he will have the option to get into the next class. but if that is true then if this guy agreed, the guy who was in the Top 2 will be now in the Top 1, and he will have the option to switch to the next class as well, and this thing will happen until this X-class run out of heroes, but apparently, this thing didn't happen in the anime.

so is this just some mistake that the author didn't notice or there is something that I'm lacking?

Answer (score 1):

That is a possibility but, in every class most of the Top 1 people will tend to remain in that class in order to try and reign over that class. That is a B class Rank 1 is most likely to flatter himself thinking that he has the potential to be in A class Top 10 and will try to control those who rank below.

If all of the Rank 1 people try to ascend to the next class the the give scenario might be possible and there are no explanations from the author till now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to be understood that the hero rankings are periodically revised<sup>1</sup>, rather than continuously updated. So, the top ranked heroes in each class A–C when the rankings are revised are then given the opportunity for promotion into the next higher class. If a hero accepts promotion, then all the heroes in that class will be bumped up by one rank, but that does not mean that the "new" top ranked hero in that class will also be offered promotion, since he was not the top ranked hero in that class when the rankings were computed in that revision.

---

<sup>1</sup>In Season 1 Episode 6, after newly receiving his hero license, Saitama finds out from Genos that a week of inactivity as a Class C hero will revoke his license. So, even if the rankings are not exactly updated every week, the data that determines a hero's ranking seems to be collected weekly.